# Duplicate Magento Store View

Tags: magento, view, translation, store, duplication

I have a Magento with many Store Views, one for every language.

Every Store View has custom settings (preferences, attribute and categories translations...) that differs from the default store values.

If I create a new Store View, the newly one uses the the default attributes.

Is there a mode from backend / programatically / via extension to duplicate an existing Store View, so all values like system preferences, translations of attributes and categories, CMS pages... has the duplicated store view values instead of the default one?

Comment: check this http://www.jarlssen.de/blog/how-to-mirror-magento-stores-configurations

Answer (score 0):

Store views are supposed to be used only if you want a different language but all other remains same. If you want some difference across stores then created a store and not a store view.Associate language to that store

Comment: I want to add a different language, but a language that is really similar to another one already inserted: as example EN_US and EN_AU. I'm looking to duplicate it because a big percentage of translations are equal and I don't have to reinsert hundreds of categories and pages translations for the new Store View but just few words.

Comment: I don't think there is a  standard way out.